# Android Splash Screen only opens if I install the app

Tags: java, android

I am a teen programmer looking for help.

I wrote a simple splash screen thingy and it only works if I uninstall and reinstall the app.

Please have a look and see if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks!

```
package ca._____.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class splash extends Activity {

 private static String TAG = splash.class.getName();
 private static long SLEEP_TIME = 5;    // Sleep for some time

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);    // Removes title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    // Removes notification bar

  setContentView(R.layout.spash_screen);

  // Start timer and launch main activity
  IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
  launcher.start();
  }

 private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
  @Override
  /**
   * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
   */
  public void run() {
     try {
        // Sleeping
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
     }

     // Start main activity
     Intent intent = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
     splash.this.startActivity(intent);
     splash.this.finish();
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to start IntentLauncher thread in onResume(), by the time activity's onResume() get called the activity is created and it will show the screen.

Second and the best thing is that you could start MainActivity in onResume() in handler like this

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

 public void run() {
  Intent intent = new Intent(splash.this, MainActivity.class);
  splash.this.startActivity(intent);
  splash.this.finish();
     }
}, 5000);
```

this is the best way.